# d:/ will be some for no reason called av_quality_[a string of numbers] of files

Tags: file, explorer

[such file in explorer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0YtnJ.png)

[Details (translated)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V7caI.png)

[Details (untranslated)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xggnG.png)

These files are empty. I want to know who made these files, this problem has been bothering me for a long time, often open D disk found a large number of similar files.